# How to get anonymous function library running with webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

I'm trying to get this module: https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries embedded in a ReactJS app that I have.

Unfortunately if I run:

`import {ElementQueries,ResizeSensor} from 'css-element-queries';`

at the top of my app, nothing happens. Any ideas?

**Update**

To clarify what I mean. The library doesn't appear to get triggered when the browser loads as it's supposed to. However if I load the console and type `ElementQueries.init();` it works.

If I put that in the React component though I get the following error:

`_cssElementQueries.ElementQueries.init is not a function`

Comment: What does "nothing happens" mean?

Comment: @loganfsmyth the library doesn't automatically load

Comment: @loganfsmyth however if I go to the browser console and type `ElementQueries.init();` it starts working. But if I put that in my React component, it gives me an error

Comment: Is it possible that the compiler is optimizing out a step that would call `ElementQueries.init` on load?

Comment: @ScottKaye it definitely is but I'm not sure how it's "optimizing".

Comment: How are you calling it in the component?

Comment: @Road Within `componentWillMount` I'm just calilng `ElementQueries.init();`

Comment: Try accessing it from `window`. It seems to be attaching it to the `window` object. `window.ElementQueries.init()`

Comment: @Road didn't work :( Unless I'm not allowed to call it but specific locations.

Comment: @NickONeill I think you will only be able to call it if it's present in the component itself? I was able to `log` it in my dev environment.

Comment: @Road that's where I call it. What are you logging exactly?

Comment: @NickONeill `componentDidMount() { console.log(window.ElementQueries); }`

Comment: @Road so that actually works apparently but it doesn't have the desired effect. It's only once everything loads that I can call it in the console :/

Comment: Are you sure that module actually exports anything, rather than setting window globals?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried: `import 'css-element-queries';`

And then access `ElementQueries` or `ResizeSensor` as a global?